# How to update a svn project if .svn folders were deleted without losing history

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I did svn checkout (git svn clone, I don't remember) for a code.google project and start using git instead.

I preserved the original project in the master git branch and I did all my changes in an additional branch named threadSafe. However, I don't have the .svn folders anymore.

Now, I need to update the project and bring the changes from the original project without loosing my changes. So, updating my git master branch from the svn project and then merging the git branches.

Can this be done if I removed the .svn folders? something like svn update

I read in stackoverflow that "You can checkout again at the same location and the svn will version all your files without downloading if there are no new updates." And I tried this, but it didn't work because it got a message saying that there are folders with the same name.

My best shot following @flopo's suggestion was: 
1. Checkout the project again using svn to another location. 
2. Copy the new checkout over my code, overwriting files. 
3. Now that I have the git master branch with the latest revision and the threadSafe git branch with my changes. Merge branches using git.

However, If I do this I lose the history of the svn repository. Becasue I appear as author of all the changes according to git.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, there is a better way for doing this but I could bring the latest updated from the svn repository to my git repository by creating an intermediate respository. Doing it like this I can preserve the history tree from the original project.

(Thank you for all the answers)

```
//Clone the svn repository using git svn and upload as a new github repository
cd src
git svn clone http://XX.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/model XX_svn
cd XX_svn
git remote add origin git@github.com:account/XX_svn.git
git push -u origin master

//add a new remote into my git project to fetch from XX_svn
cd ../XX
git remote add svnClone git://github.com/account/XX_svn.git   
git fetch svnClone
* [new branch]      master     -> svnClone/master

//merge changes as needed: merge the latest changes from the remote project to my master branch (that was an out of data copy of the original project) 
git checkout master
git merge svnClone/master

//Now, I have the latest changes from the svn repository in my git master branch --> I  can merge or cherry pick as needed. For example

git checkout thread-safe
git merge master
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Checkout the project again using SVN to another location.
2. Copy your code over this new checkout, overwriting files.
3. Synchronize the code now you have .svn folders.

Comment: Right now this is the closest I can get. But doing it in the other way around because I still have to use git.
1. Checkout the project again using svn to another location.
2. Copy the new checkout over my code, overwriting files. 
3. Now, I have the git master branch with the latest revision and the thread-safe git branch with my changes. Merge branches using git.

Comment: The only problem is that I loose the history of the original project becasue all appears as one big commit with all the changes. As if iI were the author.

Comment: Think about the importance of the old history vs the changes in git. If the old svn history is important, my approach maintains the svn history, loses the git part: you will maintain the svn history and then you will have a new commit with all the new changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--force` option for the checkout.

From the [SVN 1.7 checkout documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html):

> Prior to version 1.7, Subversion would complain by default if you try
>   to check out a directory atop an existing directory which contains
>   files or subdirectories that the checkout itself would have created.
>   Subversion 1.7 handles this situation differently, allowing the
>   checkout to proceed but marking any obstructing objects as tree
>   conflicts. Use the `--force` option to override this safeguard. When
>   you check out with the `--force` option, any unversioned file in the
>   checkout target tree which ordinarily would obstruct the checkout will
>   still become versioned, but Subversion will preserve its contents
>   as-is. If those contents differ from the repository file at that path
>   (which was downloaded as part of the checkout), the file will appear
>   to have local modifications—the changes required to transform the
>   versioned file you checked out into the unversioned file you had
>   before checking out—when the checkout completes.

Comment: The problem using --force was that it brings the new files but it doen't change the existing ones.

Comment: @tetrarquis that's the point - you don't want to change the existing files. If you want to checkout a completely fresh copy, do so in a different directory (and then rename the directory if required)

Comment: @gbjbaanb, I don't mind to change the files in the git master branch because my changes are in another git branch. But, If I do a fresh copy in a different folder then I don't have the .git folders and have the equivalent problem. I'm investigating if git svn might help to avoid loosing the svn history. Thank you!

Comment: ok, instead of rename, copy these into the old directory instead, overwriting the existing files.

Comment: @tetrarquis You said that you had preserved the original from SVN on the `master` branch. I thought you had checked out that branch in Git and were trying to get the changes from SVN so that branch could be merged into your `threadSafe` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have deleted your .svn folders, you cannot do an update, as you don't have the needed information to do that.

I'm afraid you must do a fresh checkout in another dir. You can't do a checkout in a dir with existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your repository in a fresh folder, then copy the root .svn directory into your old root folder. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an `svn status` command and you see folders or files with "!" in front of them, follow these steps to rectify the issue:

```
$ svn status
!       foo/
$ svn update foo/
$ git checkout -- foo/
$ svn status
```

Now your .svn directories should be back, with things properly showing up as modified or deleted when you run `svn status`.

**Important!** You'll want to add .svn to your .gitignore file first, if you haven't.